# kubernetes ingress service annotations

Tags: kubernetes, devops, nginx-ingress

I am setting up an ingress service following some k8s documentation, but I am not able to understand the following annotations:

`kubernetes.ip/ingress.class:`

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:`

Do you know what these annotations do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

1. `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation is officially [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#deprecating-the-ingress-class-annotation):

> Before the `IngressClass` resource was added in Kubernetes 1.18, a
> similar concept of Ingress class was often specified with a
> `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation on the Ingress. Although this
> annotation was never formally defined, it was widely supported by
> Ingress controllers, and should now be considered formally deprecated.

Instead you should use the `ingressClassName`:

> The newer `ingressClassName` field on Ingresses is a replacement for
> that annotation, but is not a direct equivalent. While the annotation
> was generally used to reference the name of the Ingress controller
> that should implement the Ingress, the field is a reference to an
> `IngressClass` resource that contains additional Ingress
> configuration, including the name of the Ingress controller.

2. The [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) does as follows:

> In some scenarios the exposed URL in the backend service differs from
> the specified path in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite any request
> will return 404. Set the annotation
> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` to the path expected by
> the service.
>
> If the Application Root is exposed in a different path and needs to be
> redirected, set the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root`
> to redirect requests for `/`.

For a more detailed example I strongly suggest you can check out this [source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). It shows exactly how rewriting works.

Answer (score 3):

Since Kubernetes **1.18**+, `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation is deprecated.
You have to create an `IngressClass` like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: alb-ingress-class
spec:
  controller: ingress.k8s.aws/alb
```

And then reference it in your `Ingress` declaration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ...
  name: my-fabulous-ingress
  annotations:
    ...
  labels:
    ...
spec:
  ingressClassName: "alb-ingress-class"
  rules:
    ...
```

**Important**: Be sure to create the `IngressClass` **before** the `Ingress` (because it is referenced by the `Ingress`)
Note: If in the same manifest, putting the `IngressClass` block above the `Ingress` one is enough.

More info:
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/ingress_class/